# How to do price sorting of product in Django (Python)?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to sort the product according to their prices, stored in the variable after extracting from a website.

The variable will contain the following details.

```
datamatch = [({'name': 'Redmi K20 Pro', 'link': 'www.exp.com', 'imglink': 'www.exp.com', 'price': '26999', 'SITE': 'flipkart'},
 {'name': 'Redmi Note 7 Pro ', 'link': 'www.exp.com', 'imglink': 'www.exp.com', 'price': '13999', 'SITE': 'flipkart'})]
```

The name of the html file is result.html and its code is given below.

result.html :

```
 {% for ab in datamatch %}
     {% for c in ab %}
          {% for a in c|dictsort:"a.price" %}
              <div class="center">
                 <div class="a">
                    <div class="p">
                       <div class="card horizontal col m4 ">
                          <div class="card-stacked">
                             <div class="card-content">
                                <div class="animated bounce">
                                   <div class="card-title black-text text-darken-4">
                                       <h4 style="text-align:left;">{{ a.name}}</h4><h5 style="text-align:left;">{{ a.SITE }}</h5>
                                         <ul style="text-align:left;">
                                             <li>Category: {{ a.link }} </li>
                                             <li>Sale Price: {{ a.price </li>
                                             <li>Image link: {{ a.imglink }}</li>
                                             <li> Availability: <span class="new badge green" >{{ a.imglink }}</span></li></ul>
                                              <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn m" href="{{ a.URL }}" style="align:right;"><i class="large material-icons right">play_arrow </i>View</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}  
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}       `
```

I tried with the above code and it returns nothing. but, as soon as i delete the 
(|dictsort:"a.price") it retuns the product but not in descending order of price.

Note: I want to do it with the help of django code compulsorily and not with python

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

a few things to note here

1) Django's templating language is slow so it is better to write it before passing into request. 
2) You might be able to get rid of a for loop. It is currently a dictionary in a set in a list.
3) The prices are strings instead of integers.
4) It would also help to see the template tag function dictsort

My recommendation is to use this before passing into the request.

```
#Optionally make this a template tag, however outside of templating language is best.
def dictsort(datamatch):
  new_data_match = []
  for data in datamatch:
    for row in data:
      row['price'] = int(row['price'])
      new_data_match.append(row)

  new_list = sorted(new_data_match, key=lambda k: k['price'])

  return datamatch
```